# Media Queries issue with Ipad and Android Tablet

Tags: css

I am facing an issue with Ipad and Android Tablets media Queries especially in landscape mode.

I need some help regarding with the proper media queries.

here are the media queries that I am using:

Android Landscape:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 800px) and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation : landscape) {}
```

Ipad Landscape:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {}
```

Comment: I think the `orientation` will suffice. No need for `(min|max)-device-width`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@media (min-width : 800px) and (max-width: 1280px) {}
@media (min-width : 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}
```

for reference

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for android tab:

@media (min-device-width : 600px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {}

and

@media (min-device-width : 600px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {}